# How to say if I understand how my injured friend feels?

Tags: sentence-construction

Suppose my friend has broken his arm and I've experienced the same. How to say if I understand how hurt it did?

The phrase I could think of is "I feel you" but, in my opinion, it's so awkward and sounds weird if I say that to my friend.

Comment: You can say "I feel _for_ you".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could say something like:

> I know what it feels like
> I know what you are going through

There is also an expression "[I feel your pain](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/i-feel-your-his-etc-pain)", but it generally refers to mental anguish rather than physical pain- often used ironically to somebody who is over-reacting to a trivial problem.